# Calling async method in catch block

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, async-await

I'm working in async environment (Silverlight) and have Logger service that I use to store exceptions on server-side.

Consider this code:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.loggerService.LogAsync(ex, "NotesService");
    }
```

Logger looks like this:

```
public interface ILoggerService
    {
        Task LogAsync(Exception ex, string tag);
    }
```

If I write code as above (even catch is in async method) I can't put await there.
If I leave it as is I get warning that execution continues, blah, blah. Which is fine, I don't care. I just need to get error logged.

Can I just supress this warning or should I come up with better pattern for this?

Comment: What do you want to do if `LogAsync` fails completely? You might want to have a backup plan for observing the faulted task.

Comment: @JonSkeet I code LogAsync in such way where I "eat" exception - this is last resort..

Comment: @katit: In that case you might want to *consider* changing the return type to `void`. That's very *very* rarely a good idea, but if you *really* want it to be completely "fire and forget" it will work.

Comment: The more I learn this pattern and seeing how "async all way" naturally becomes required - it seems like top method almost always will be void :(

Comment: @katit If you're in a GUI environment (like Silverlight) and the top method is an event handler, then yes. That's the only situation where you don't have to think hard if using `async void` is really the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're absolutely sure you want to ignore completion/errors from `LogAsync`, you can do this simple workaround:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var _ = this.loggerService.LogAsync(ex, "NotesService");
}
```